# Have file directory open ONLY when certain button is pressed, and not automatically

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I am trying to have the file directory open when a certain button is pressed in the tkinter GUI, but the directory automatically opens when I run the program. Addittionally, if I press cancel when in the file directory, my program freezes up and I have to close the program, and I'm not sure why this is.

I tried putting all of the tkinter related coding in a seperate file, but when I tried to call a method from that file, it would open up the tkinter GUI twice, so that didn't work and I wasn't able to solve the problem, so I thought combining the two would make it a little easier. I was able to have the tkinter GUI stop appearing twice, but now I am at this dilemma. I tried using the debugger that comes with spyder, but it wasn't able to help much besides showing me why the tkinter GUI kept appearing twice.

```
import os
import PyPDF2
import pandas
import webbrowser
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

#Creats the GUI that will be used to select inputs#
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")
window.resizable(0, 0)
window.title("Word Frequency Program")

#Allows user to select PDF to use in program#
def select_PDF():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select file", filetypes = (("pdf files", "*.pdf"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    return filename
button1 = ttk.Button(window, text = "Select File", command = select_PDF)
button1.grid()

#Quits out of the program when certain button clicked#
button3 = ttk.Button(window, text = "Quit", command = window.quit)
button3.grid()

#Loads in PDF into program#
filepath = select_PDF()
PDF_file = open(filepath, 'rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(PDF_file)

#Determines number of pages in PDF file and sets the document content to 'null'#
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
doc_content = ""

#Extract text from the PDF file#
for i in range(number_of_pages):
    page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
    page_content = page.extractText()
    doc_content += page_content

#Method that a pdf that is read into the program goes through to eliminate any unwanted words or symbols#
def preprocess(text):
    #Filters out punctuation from paragraph witch becomes tokenized to words and punctuation#
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    result = tokenizer.tokenize(text)

    #Makes all words lowercase#
    words = [item.lower() for item in result]

    #Removes all remaining tokens that are not alphabetic#
    result = [word for word in words if word.isalpha()]

    #Imports stopwords to be removed from paragraph#
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))

    #Removes the stop words from the paragraph#
    filtered_sent = []
    for w in result:
        if w not in stop_words:
            filtered_sent.append(w)

    #Return word to root word/chop-off derivational affixes#
    ps = PorterStemmer()
    stemmed_words = []
    for w in filtered_sent:
        stemmed_words.append(ps.stem(w))

    #Lemmatization, which reduces word to their base word, which is linguistically correct lemmas#
    lem = WordNetLemmatizer()
    lemmatized_words = ' '.join([lem.lemmatize(w,'n') and lem.lemmatize(w,'v') for w in filtered_sent])

    #Re-tokenize lemmatized words string#
    tokenized_word = word_tokenize(lemmatized_words)
    return tokenized_word

#Turns the text drawn from the PDF file into data the remaining code can understand#
tokenized_words = preprocess(doc_content)

#Determine frequency of words tokenized + lemmatized text#
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
fdist = FreqDist(tokenized_words)
final_list = fdist.most_common(len(fdist))

#Organize data into two columns and export the data to an html that automatically opens#
df = pandas.DataFrame(final_list, columns = ["Word", "Frequency"])
df.to_html('word_frequency.html')
webbrowser.open('file://' + os.path.realpath('word_frequency.html'))

window.mainloop()
window.destroy()
```

The tkinter GUI should pop up on its own without the file directory appearing UNTIL you press a button in the GUI. The program also should not crash when you press cancel in the file directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run after pressing Button then you have to run all code inside `select_PDF`

```
button1 = ttk.Button(window, text="Select File", command=select_PDF)

def select_PDF():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select file", filetypes = (("pdf files", "*.pdf"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    #Loads in PDF into program#
    PDF_file = open(filename, 'rb')
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(PDF_file)

    #Determines number of pages in PDF file and sets the document content to 'null'#
    number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
    doc_content = ""

    #Extract text from the PDF file#

    # ... rest of code ...
```

`Button` doesn't works like `input()` - it doesn't stop code and doesn't wait for your click. It only defines button and `mainloop()` will display it. You should

Your code should be like this:

```
import os
import PyPDF2
import pandas
import webbrowser
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

# --- functions ---

def preprocess(text):
    '''Method that a pdf that is read into the program goes through to eliminate any unwanted words or symbols'''

    #Filters out punctuation from paragraph witch becomes tokenized to words and punctuation#
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    result = tokenizer.tokenize(text)

    #Makes all words lowercase#
    words = [item.lower() for item in result]

    #Removes all remaining tokens that are not alphabetic#
    result = [word for word in words if word.isalpha()]

    #Imports stopwords to be removed from paragraph#
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))

    #Removes the stop words from the paragraph#
    filtered_sent = []
    for w in result:
        if w not in stop_words:
            filtered_sent.append(w)

    #Return word to root word/chop-off derivational affixes#
    ps = PorterStemmer()
    stemmed_words = []
    for w in filtered_sent:
        stemmed_words.append(ps.stem(w))

    #Lemmatization, which reduces word to their base word, which is linguistically correct lemmas#
    lem = WordNetLemmatizer()
    lemmatized_words = ' '.join([lem.lemmatize(w,'n') and lem.lemmatize(w,'v') for w in filtered_sent])

    #Re-tokenize lemmatized words string#
    tokenized_word = word_tokenize(lemmatized_words)
    return tokenized_word

def select_PDF():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select file", filetypes = (("pdf files", "*.pdf"), ("all files", "*.*")))

    PDF_file = open(filename, 'rb')
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(PDF_file)

    #Determines number of pages in PDF file and sets the document content to 'null'#
    number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
    doc_content = ""

    #Extract text from the PDF file#
    for i in range(number_of_pages):
        page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
        page_content = page.extractText()
        doc_content += page_content

    #Turns the text drawn from the PDF file into data the remaining code can understand#
    tokenized_words = preprocess(doc_content)

    #Determine frequency of words tokenized + lemmatized text#
    from nltk.probability import FreqDist
    fdist = FreqDist(tokenized_words)
    final_list = fdist.most_common(len(fdist))

    #Organize data into two columns and export the data to an html that automatically opens#
    df = pandas.DataFrame(final_list, columns = ["Word", "Frequency"])
    df.to_html('word_frequency.html')
    webbrowser.open('file://' + os.path.realpath('word_frequency.html'))

# --- main ---

#Creats the GUI that will be used to select inputs#
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")
window.resizable(0, 0)
window.title("Word Frequency Program")

button1 = ttk.Button(window, text = "Select File", command=select_PDF)
button1.grid()

#Quits out of the program when certain button clicked#
button3 = ttk.Button(window, text="Quit", command=window.quit)
button3.grid()

window.mainloop()
window.destroy()
```

---

Or you can use button to select filename, keep it in global variable and close window (`window.quit()`) and rest of code put after `mainloop()`. `mainloop()` will wait till you close window and all code after `mainloop()` will be executed after you select file (and close window)

```
import os
import PyPDF2
import pandas
import webbrowser
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

# --- functions ---

def preprocess(text):
    '''Method that a pdf that is read into the program goes through to eliminate any unwanted words or symbols'''

    #Filters out punctuation from paragraph witch becomes tokenized to words and punctuation#
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    result = tokenizer.tokenize(text)

    #Makes all words lowercase#
    words = [item.lower() for item in result]

    #Removes all remaining tokens that are not alphabetic#
    result = [word for word in words if word.isalpha()]

    #Imports stopwords to be removed from paragraph#
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))

    #Removes the stop words from the paragraph#
    filtered_sent = []
    for w in result:
        if w not in stop_words:
            filtered_sent.append(w)

    #Return word to root word/chop-off derivational affixes#
    ps = PorterStemmer()
    stemmed_words = []
    for w in filtered_sent:
        stemmed_words.append(ps.stem(w))

    #Lemmatization, which reduces word to their base word, which is linguistically correct lemmas#
    lem = WordNetLemmatizer()
    lemmatized_words = ' '.join([lem.lemmatize(w,'n') and lem.lemmatize(w,'v') for w in filtered_sent])

    #Re-tokenize lemmatized words string#
    tokenized_word = word_tokenize(lemmatized_words)
    return tokenized_word

def select_PDF():
    global filename # to assign to global variable

    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select file", filetypes = (("pdf files", "*.pdf"), ("all files", "*.*")))

    window.close() # close 

# --- main ---

filename = None # create global variable with default value at start

#Creats the GUI that will be used to select inputs#
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")
window.resizable(0, 0)
window.title("Word Frequency Program")

button1 = ttk.Button(window, text = "Select File", command=select_PDF)
button1.grid()

#Quits out of the program when certain button clicked#
button3 = ttk.Button(window, text="Quit", command=window.quit)
button3.grid()

window.mainloop()
window.destroy()

# --- executed after closing window ---

if filename: # check if filename was selected

    PDF_file = open(filename, 'rb')
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(PDF_file)

    #Determines number of pages in PDF file and sets the document content to 'null'#
    number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
    doc_content = ""

    #Extract text from the PDF file#
    for i in range(number_of_pages):
        page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
        page_content = page.extractText()
        doc_content += page_content


    #Turns the text drawn from the PDF file into data the remaining code can understand#
    tokenized_words = preprocess(doc_content)

    #Determine frequency of words tokenized + lemmatized text#
    from nltk.probability import FreqDist
    fdist = FreqDist(tokenized_words)
    final_list = fdist.most_common(len(fdist))

    #Organize data into two columns and export the data to an html that automatically opens#
    df = pandas.DataFrame(final_list, columns = ["Word", "Frequency"])
    df.to_html('word_frequency.html')
    webbrowser.open('file://' + os.path.realpath('word_frequency.html'))
```

Comment: Okay thank you, I was able to get it to work properly by placing everything besides the buttons and the preprocess method inside the select_PDF method.

Comment: for PDF_file, it should be PDF_file = open(filepath, 'rb') correct? I don't want to make any corrections to your code unless what you did was intentional

Comment: there was mistake - I copied your code and there was `filepath`. It has to be `filename` instead of `filepath` - `PDF_file = open(filename, 'rb')`.

Comment: gotcha thank you. I may have more questions in the coming weeks regarding this program, however it is almost complete.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is the file picker opening before you click the button, then this line is probably causing the issue:

```py
#Loads in PDF into program#
filepath = select_PDF()
PDF_file = open(filepath, 'rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(PDF_file)
```

You're calling `select_PDF()`, and that in turn opens the file picker. When you click "Cancel", it probably returns `None` or something like that to the next line, which tries to open an invalid filepath.

Comment: Okay that helps me understand why the code wasn't working in the first place, thank you